# Connect to Server not Accepting my Password in pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql

I just installed postgres 12.3 on my Mac Mojave 10.14.6. When I open pgadmin4 I'm prompted for a password for the postgres user I set up in the installation. I enter this password and connect without issue, however when I try to connect to the server itself I'm prompted again for a password I enter the same password and I get the following error:

FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Important consideration I uninstalled and reinstalled postgres recently.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Are there two passwords I should be aware of ?

Is there a way I can reset this password?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html, you need to set ```pg-hba.conf``` config file.

Comment: I get permission denied when I try to access this file.  Any ideas?

Comment: ```sudo``` before the command to edit

Comment: and restart postgres service after change pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and that's what helped me:

1. Uninstall the server by runing "open uninstall-postgresql.app" in the following path: "Library/PostgreSQL/12"
   (you can see further instructions in [this link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/postgresql/installation-getting-started/installation-guide-installers/11/PostgreSQL_Installation_Guide.1.12.html))
2. Delete the data folder located in the same path "sudo rm -rf data"
3. Reinstall the server and make sure you choose a simple password (1-6 is enough, you'll replace it later)
4. Open pgAdmin and try to connect to your server
   at this point you will be prompted to enter the password and below the textbox you'll find a "reset password" button, click it and choose new password
   now you'll be able to log in with your new password